# .live event doesnt work till second click

Tags: jquery

I have 2 list on a page that are linked.  When I drag a li element from list 1 to list 2 the live events on list 1 don't work on the first click only second click.  Below is the code that adds the li (obj) to list 2.

```
function AddToDropBox(obj) {
    $(obj).children(".handle").animate({ width: "20px" }).children("strong").fadeOut();
    $(obj).children("span:not(.track,.play,.handle,:has(.btn-edit))").fadeOut('fast');
    $(obj).children(".play").css("margin-right", "8px");
    $(obj).css({ "opacity": "0.0", "width": "284px" }).animate({ opacity: "1.0" });
    if ($(".sidebar-drop-box ul").children(".admin-song").length > 0) {
        $(".dropTitle").fadeOut("fast");
        $(".sidebar-drop-box ul.admin-song-list").css("min-height", "0");
    }
    if (typeof SetLinks == 'function') {
        SetLinks();
    }
//CBG Changes adds media ID to hidden field
    //checks id there is a value in field then adds comma
    if(document.getElementById("ctl00_cphBody_hfRemoveMedia").value==""||document.getElementById("ctl00_cphBody_hfRemoveMedia").value==null)
    {
    document.getElementById("ctl00_cphBody_hfRemoveMedia").value=(obj).attr("mediaid");
    }
    else
    {
    var localMediaIDs=document.getElementById("ctl00_cphBody_hfRemoveMedia").value;
    document.getElementById("ctl00_cphBody_hfRemoveMedia").value=localMediaIDs+", "+(obj).attr("mediaid");
    }
//    alert("hfid: "+document.getElementById("ctl00_cphBody_hfRemoveMedia").value);
//END CBG Modifications
}
```

this is one of the live() events that dont fire until the second click after the drag.  This live() event is in a document.ready function().

```
// Live for deleting.
    $(".btn-del").live("click", function(e) {
        DeleteItem(this);
        $(this).removeClass("btn-del").addClass("btn-add").parents("li").removeClass("alt").addClass("removed");
        var oldTxt = $(this).parents("li").find(".status").text();
        $(this).parents("li").find(".status").text("Removed").attr("oldstat", oldTxt);
        $("#timeHolder input[type=hidden]").val(($("#timeHolder input[type=hidden]").val() * 1) - ($(this).parents("li").find(".time").attr("length") * 1));
        CalculateAggregates();
        isDirty = false;
    });
```

**EDIT**
@dreaton.. Im new to jquery and javascript so thanks for the last tip... Im not sure what you mean about cache the query's. ... the delegete feature is giving me this *Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method*

this is the way I have the code

```
$('#ulPlaylist').delegate('.btn-del', 'click', function (e) {
        DeleteItem(this);
        $(this).removeClass("btn-del").addClass("btn-add").parents("li").removeClass("alt").addClass("removed");
        var oldTxt = $(this).parents("li").find(".status").text();
        $(this).parents("li").find(".status").text("Removed").attr("oldstat", oldTxt);
        $("#timeHolder input[type=hidden]").val(($("#timeHolder input[type=hidden]").val() * 1) - ($(this).parents("li").find(".time").attr("length") * 1));
        CalculateAggregates();
        isDirty = false;
    });
```

Update:

after the drag and drop all jquery and javascript functionality seems to be gone.  when I do a reverse drag and drop the the javascript function that handles that event doenst fire either.

```
function AddToLeftList(obj) {
    $(obj).children(".handle").animate({ width: "50px" }).children("strong").fadeIn();
    $(obj).find("span:has(.btn-edit)").hide();
    $(obj).children("span:not(:has(.btn-edit))").fadeIn('fast');
    $(obj).children(".play").css("margin-right", "auto");
    $(obj).children("[smallonly]").remove();
    $(obj).css({ "opacity": "0.0", "width": "610px" }).animate({ opacity: "1.0" });
    CheckLeftList();
    if (typeof SetLinks == 'function') {
        SetLinks();
    }
```

above the javascript that doesnt excute.  I am not sure that helps but i realize that all the functionality from javascript and jquery dont execute on the first user action.  only after the second.

Comment: Regarding caching queries: each call to $('selector') instantiates a new instance of jQuery. This hogs memory and slows performance by performing the same selection multiple times. If you store the selection in a variable, you can still access all of the jQuery methods from that variable. So "$this = $(this); $this.removeClass('btn-del'); $this.parents('li').find('.status').text(); ..."

Comment: Regarding the runtime error, can you set up a jsFiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/? Or at least provide the line that throws the error.

Comment: this is the line that throws the error "$('#ulPlaylist').delegate('.btn-del', 'click', function (e) {"

Comment: I might be leading you down a dead-end. $.fn.delegate was added in jQuery 1.4.2. What version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Not being sure of your HTML structure, it is difficult to answer, but I prefer to use $.fn.delegate(). Let's assume your parent holder id is 'parentid'. So:

```
$('#parentid').delegate('.btn-del', 'click', function (e) {
    // event handler stuff here
    // this refers to whatever element matches '.btn-del', not the parent element
});
```

Please cache your queries:

```
var $obj = $(obj);
```

Also, if you're using jQuery, no need for document.getElementById('blahblah').value; use:

```
$('#blahblah').val()
```

Comment: i tried the delegate and got an error, I updated my initial post with comments